# How to add a board file to the Linux Kernel and where to find it on "make menu config"?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, device-tree, kbuild

I need to add some board-specific code to a Linux kernel which I am building.

(I know I should be using device-tree already, but the driver I'm inspired by doesn't and I'm already learning a dozen new things before breakfast.  Adding device-tree will also add another set of changes to debug.  Once I have my platform-driver/drivers working using a board file, I will convert them to device tree.)

I have a file called `arch/arm/myboard/myboard.c`.

Where do I find existing board files in `make menuconfig`?  (Such as http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-imx/mach-mx31ads.c?v=4.4 ?)

How do I make my board appear here also.

Comment: Take a look at Kconfig and Makefile in the http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-imx/?v=4.4. For example Kconfig declare MACH_MX31MOBOARD variable and that variable is used in Makefile to build board specific code.

Comment: Actually you can just hard code the platform info in the device driver for now, and use DT when you want them configurable.

Comment: @user3528438 Great idea, this will save me a lot of time.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You need to patch the driver to support Device Tree. It's really easiest and right way.

Comment: @user3528438 Hardcode?!

Comment: @chrisdew I wouldn't call it a great idea. How is device/driver matching is supposed to happen? You driver's `probe()` function won't be executed. Sure, you can add some `module_init()` or something like that, but this way you would miss the whole point of **driver**, reducing it to just some dull module. Yes, you should do one step at a time, but I'd argue that the order is off. First, create device tree and initial code for your platform, and only then develop your driver. [See this for details](http://free-electrons.com/pub/conferences/2015/captronic/captronic-porting-linux-on-arm.pdf#f).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [`Makefile` in the same directory](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-imx/Makefile?v=4.4).  For *mach-mx31ads.c*, it has,

```
# i.MX31 based machines
 obj-$(CONFIG_MACH_MX31ADS) += mach-mx31ads.o
```

The Kconfig has a corresponding entry,

```
 config MACH_MX31ADS
         bool "Support MX31ADS platforms"
         default y
         select IMX_HAVE_PLATFORM_IMX_I2C
         select IMX_HAVE_PLATFORM_IMX_SSI
         select IMX_HAVE_PLATFORM_IMX_UART
         select SOC_IMX31
         help
           Include support for MX31ADS platform. This includes specific
           configurations for the board and its peripherals.
```

Adding these will give your board a Kconfig menu item and build the file.  The only other missing piece is a **machine type**.  You need to add this to [arm/tools/mach-type](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/tools/mach-types?v=4.4) which is processed by the kernel makefile, using the [gen-mach-types](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/tools/gen-mach-types?v=4.4) script, to create a *generated/mach-type.h*.  You use this in your board file to create a static machine description (put in a special section).

```
 MACHINE_START(MX31ADS, "Freescale MX31ADS")
         /* Maintainer: Freescale Semiconductor, Inc. */
         .atag_offset = 0x100,
         .map_io = mx31ads_map_io,
         .init_early = imx31_init_early,
         .init_irq = mx31ads_init_irq,
         .init_time      = mx31ads_timer_init,
         .init_machine = mx31ads_init,
         .restart        = mxc_restart,
 MACHINE_END
```

The `machine_desc` structure is found in [arch.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/mach/arch.h?v=4.4).  You don't need to add all the elements as they won't be called if not present.  The kernel init looks a the machine ATAG and iterates through the sections to match the machine that the boot loader passes in.  Locating the `machine_desc` is done in assembler very early in the linux boot.